# Class<T,C> and Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

Here is some class:

```
public class MyClass<T, C> : IMyClass where T : SomeTClass
                                              where C : SomeCClass
{
    private T t;
    private C c;


    public MyClass()
    {
        this.t= Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        this.c= Activator.CreateInstance<C>();
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to instanciate object of this class by doing this:

```
            Type type = typeof(MyClass<,>).MakeGenericType(typeOfSomeTClass, typeOfSomeCClass);
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

And all I get is a `System.MissingMethodException`(there is no no-arg constructor for this object)...

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: That should work assuming `LigneGrille` and `MyClass` are the same class, and your two arguments are in fact `typeof(SomeTClass)` and `typeof(SomeCClass)`. Where exactly is the exception occurring?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to change `LigneGrille` to `MyClass`?

Comment: If you include the new() constraint (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5(v=vs.80).aspx) your code will be much simpler.

Comment: Stupid question perhaps, but did you check that `typeOfSomeTClass` and `typeOfSomeCClass` have public empty constructors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like `typeOfSomeTClass` or `typeOfSomeCClass` is a type that doesn't have a public parameterless constructor, as required by:

```
this.t = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
this.c = Activator.CreateInstance<C>();
```

You could enforce that via a constraint:

```
where T : SomeTClass, new()
where C : SomeCClass, new()
```

in which case you can also then do:

```
this.t = new T();
this.c = new C();
```

Comment: oh... it requires a public parameterless constructor even if there is no constructor at all. I'll try.

Comment: @Francois only a `static` class has "no constructor at all"...  note: it *is* possible to create an object without using any constructor, but it should be reserved for specific scenarios (usually: deserialization)

Comment: Yes, by "no constructor at all" I was meaning no visible constructor. I guess that if you don't declare a constructor, there is the public one?

Comment: @FrancoisB for a regular `class`, yes, you'll get a `public` parameterless constructor. For an `abstract class` you'll get a `protected` parameterless constructor; an `interface` or a `static class` gets nothing; a `struct` lives in an odd middle ground of not *actually* having a parameterless constructor (in CLI terms), but yet *having* a public parameterless constructor (in C# terms) at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailled answer. All my tests are green!

Answer (score 0):

MakeGenericType should use an array of Type in this context.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx

For example

Type type = typeof(LigneGrille<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] {typeOfSomeTClass, typeOfSomeCClass});

Comment: The code in the question is fine; `MakeGenericType` is declared with a `params Type[]`, so the compiler creates the `Type[]` itself.